# SSRS PDF export errors

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS 2005 report, the report has two groups and one nested table inside of a group, the report is displayed correctly in VS as two pages, but when trying to export it to PDF I get 17 pages and the only correct pages I get are at the end of the PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

Check the grid vs the Page Size.

If you Page Size is set to 8.5" x 11 and you have 1" margins and your Grid (The "white" part of the report) goes beyond the margins, you will get overflow on to other pages.

If you look at the picture below, you can see the grid goes just beyond the 7" mark.  My interactive snf Page Sizes are set to 8.5 x 11.  This exports fine.  A good way to check is to switch to "Print Layout" mode.  You can do this by clicking on the little icon that looks like a white piece of paper on a green background just to the right of the Printer Icon.  When you view it this way, you get a pretty good idea of how it will be exported.

I have run into this problem before, generally a Table or Rectangle control will inadvertently push to the edge of the Grid and in turn increase the size of the Grid beyond your paper size and margins.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's been a (long) while since I worked with SSRS. I remember having adjusted rsreportserver.config
This link should help:
[Customizing rendering extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156281.aspx)
The link is just the result of quick googling. Didn't read it through.

I had to adjust values for i.e. border width and so on, which are by default somehow a mess. And if that doesn't help, you have to adjust your report.